# Can cloudflare work at apache 2.0

Tags: cloudflare

I cant find this answer anywhere on their site, but does anyone know if cloudflare will work on Apache version 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about this be because of [mod_cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads)?

CloudFlare can work with any site & does not depend on the server type being used. The question generally comes up when it is related to [restoring original visitor IP with CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-).

Comment: Yes I am, I enabled it on some of my sites with bluehost.com and when it enabled it brought down all my sites. Found out it was the cloudflare.conf file. Once I commented out the first line of that file the error went away, not sure if its still working. I have apache 2.0